# Select parent selector when child is checked in SCSS/SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

Hello guys I have a very newbie question here but can't find a way to fix:

```
.parent {
  justify-content:left;

  .child__checkbox {
  // properties
  &:checked {
   justify-content:right;  
   } 
  }
```

When the `.child__checkbox` is checked, the `.parent` property should change from `justify-content:left` to `justify-content:right` without affecting the properties of `.child__checkbox`.

How do you do this?

Comment: You should give an example including the basic HTML you're working with for a question like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, javascript would be more apropriated, since as of now we dont have a way to affect a parent element like this that works across all browsers.